# Order of Views Element in Grails not same as defined in domain constraint

Tags: grails

I have made a model in Grails, then through command I am generating `view` and `controller` using `generate-all com.liftoff.Person` but my order of view element is not same as I defined in the constraints.

**Grails version 2.2.4**

Any suggestion for resolve this problem ??

```
package com.liftoff

class Person {

    String studentID
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    String year
    boolean isMarried

    static constraints = {
        studentID ()
        firstName ()
        middleName ()
        lastName ()
        year ()
        isMarried ()
    }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: It will come as you mention order in constraints. delete view folder and recreate it.clean the project again

Comment: @Visme I did that , deleted view, controller, target and then run again `generate-all` but still have same thing

Comment: what version you are using. for me it is working fine.

Comment: I am using grails-2.2.4

Comment: Works as expected in 2.3.7. I think it might be an issue with that version of Grails where the views generated from templates is not maintaining the order. You can try `grails install-template` and see if you can modify the behavior by modifying the templates. After modification, you have to issue `generate-all` once again though.